# Making my C# application manageable via PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I would like to create PowerShell cmdlets that interact with my application at runtime. Are there any best practices on how to accomplish this?

Comment: what exactly you want to do between powershell and your application?

Comment: i would like to execute some methods defined in my application and pass to them the output from standard powershell commands

Comment: it is possible to execute your application from powershell, you can pass parameters from powershell to your application also. Additionally, you can execute powershell commands from your application like             string powershellcommand = "tree";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("powershell.exe", powershellcommand);

Comment: Are you expecting these commands to interact with a already running instance of your application or are you wanting your application to just be a powershell commandlet?

Comment: I want these commands to interact with my application at runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options.  You could some form of IPC mechanism: named pipes, memory mapped files, MSMQ, etc.  The cmdlets could communicate to the app via a socket.  If the app is managed, it could host a WCF endpoint that the cmdlets could use to communicate with the app.  You could also expose a COM API and then control the app via that API.  I'm sure there are several other ways I've failed to mention.